# React Native with WebSocket doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, react-native

I heard that Socket.io not worked properly in React Native, so I decided to use plain WebSocket instead.

I'm using node.js for implemeting WebSocket server, and it wasn't hard. With browsers, all of I tried worked, but with React native, none of success.

These are what I tried for implementing websocket server:

- express-ws
- ws

express-ws was just not worked without any error message. Just it saids failed to connect something.

So I changed the module to ws, and this module should be required both client and server, so I did. Server was worked, but when in the app with android on AVD, it saids:

> Requiring unknown module "url".If you are sure the module is there,
>   try restarting the packager or running "npm install".

So I removed node_modules directory entirely and reinstall them, but same error shown up again.

I'm using node v6.2.2, and react-native-cli 1.0.0, react-native 0.33.0.

This is the server code with ws module(same as ws module readme):

```
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;
var wss = new WebSocketServer({ port: 3000 });

wss.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.on('message', (msg) => {
        console.log('Received: ' + msg);
    });

    socket.send('something');
});
```

This is client:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    AppRegistry,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View
} from 'react-native';

const WebSocket = require('ws');

class wschat extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        var socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:3000");

        socket.on('open', () => {
            socket.send('something');
        });
        socket.on('message', (data, flags) => {
            console.log(data);
            console.log(flags);
        });
    }
    ...
```

To avoid naming conflict, I was used WebSock instead WebSocket when requiring ws module, but it wasn't problem.

Is there a something that I missed? React Native doc has not much explanations, and it is hard to find working examples. Thanks for reading, and any advice will very appreciate it.

Comment: I also stuck with this issue, first try to remove
 `const WebSocket = require('ws')`
WebSicket are provided by default in RN.
Let me know if it worked

Comment: I had a similar issue where I also used `localhost:3000` in the RN code until I figured that my backend wasn't running on my device's `localhost`, but on my computer's `localhost`. Once I replaced it with my local IP address, it worked.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The latest `react native` supports websocket, so we don't have to depend on 3rd party websocket client library.

The following example is based on `react native 0.45`, and the project is generated by `create-react-native-app`.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Text, View} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            echo: ''
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        var socket = new WebSocket('wss://echo.websocket.org/');

        socket.onopen = () => socket.send(new Date().toGMTString());

        socket.onmessage = ({data}) => {
            console.log(data);

            this.setState({echo: data});

            setTimeout(() => {
                socket.send(new Date().toGMTString());
            }, 3000);
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>websocket echo: {this.state.echo}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: i did implement the connection with no problem with websockets but it's not sending messages at all(react native )  like socket.send.... does not work on react native

Answer (score 1):

Install this package `npm install websocket` on your react native folder. The link to the relevant Github repo is [this](https://github.com/theturtle32/WebSocket-Node)

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { w3cwebsocket as W3CWebSocket } from "websocket";
import { Text} from 'react-native';

var client = new W3CWebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/', 'echo-protocol');

function App() {

    client.onopen = function() {
    console.log('WebSocket Client Connected');

      function sendNumber() {
         if (client.readyState === client.OPEN) {
            var number = Math.round(Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF);
            client.send(number.toString());
            setTimeout(sendNumber, 1000);
         }
      }
      sendNumber();
     };

     client.onclose = function() {
       console.log('echo-protocol Client Closed');
     };

     client.onmessage = function(e) {
        if (typeof e.data === 'string') {
          console.log("Received: '" + e.data + "'");
        }
    };  
    return (
     
        <Text>Practical Intro To WebSockets.</Text>
     
    );
}

export default App;
```